# "You have already flagged this post" message should enable the "I'm Done" button

Tags: feature-request, review

When I'm reviewing, I go to /review and open up a tab for every post that needs reviewing (so if there are four Low Quality posts, I will open four windows, one with each post in it).

As I work through all of the open windows, I may decide to flag or delete a post. This post may then appear in one of the other tabs but since it hasn't updated that I've flagged it, the "I'm Done" button is greyed out. Additionally, flagging it again brings up the error prompt stating that you've already flagged, as you'd expect:

[image]

As a workaround you simply reload the page and this will correctly display the "I'm Done" button enabled and ready to be clicked.

Would it be possible that triggering this message also enables the "I'm Done" button?

Comment: Not necessarily a good way of working as these queues are changed often, surely the last one you get round too will already have been reviewed by someone else.

Comment: I'm normally the first person to the reviews on most sites I actively review on so this issue occurs very rarely and the system handles it fine.